# Finding the roots of a trig function

Tags: calculus

I need help finding the roots of:

$$F(x)=3\sin2x-4x+1$$ with the interval of $[-2\pi,2\pi]$

to the nearest $0.001$.

Graphical method preferred but numerical methods also appreciated.

I used the "Zero" function on my Ti-84 to solve the previous equation.
Here is my sheet:

> 46. Given $f(x)=x^4-3x^3+2x^2-7x-11$
>       Find all roots to the nearest $0.001$
>
> *Root 1 $x=-.911$
>
>   Root 2 $x=3.329$*
>
> 47. Given: $f(x)=3\sin2x-4x+1$ from $[-2\pi,2\pi]$
>       Find all roots to the nearest $0.001$
>       [NOTE: all trig functions are done in radian mode]
>
> *$A=3\quad K=\pi$
>
>   Max $\pi+3$
>
>   Min $\pi-3$*
>
> 48. Given $f(x)=0.7x^2+3.2x+1.5$
>       Find all roots to the nearest $0.001$
>
> $x=-4.041,-.530$

Comment: I'm assuming you can use numerical methods here? Is there a particular numerical method you have been learning or is this a standalone problem that you have to figure out yourself?

Comment: in the previous question i was given f(x)=x^4-3x^3+2x^2-7x-11 and i was told to use "zero" under "calc", other than that i dont know what i can and cant do in terms of solving this equation.

Comment: What does that mean? Which numerical methods are you allowed to use?

Comment: @notnek on the ti-84 if you press "2nd" then "trace" you open up the calc menu, under number 2 you will find "zero". It will then ask you for "left bound", "right bound", and "guess"

Comment: You should have mentioned that you're meant to use a graphical calcualor in your original post. I don't use one so I can't help you. If this problem is meant to be done entirely using a graphical calculator then please edit your original post to say this.

Comment: @notnek If you can solve it using a numerical method, that would help a lot as well.

Comment: There are too many comments here. Please edit your original post to tell us exactly what you want.

Comment: Your graphing calculator uses Newton's Method to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest numerical method to use is in my opinion Newton's method which is:

$$  x_n= x_{n-1} - \frac{f(x_{\color{red}{n-1}})}{f'(x_{\color{red}{n-1}})} $$

Here we seek the root of :
$$f(x)=3 \sin 2x -4x +1 \implies f'(x)=6\cos(2x)-4 $$

Now we choose a starting point for $x_0$ ( Make a reasonable guess by either sketching the function or using your gut). Let's take $x_0=0$

Then we begin the iteration:
$$x_1=x_0-\frac{f(0)}{f'(0)}= 0 - \frac{1}{2} = -\frac{1}{2}$$ 
$$x_2=x_1-\frac{f(x_1)}{f'(x_1)}= - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{0.476}{-0.758} ....$$

And so on, we stop the iteration once $x_{n+1}=x_n$ to 3 decimal places and we discover, just like what Khadija Mbarki stated, the root is at: $$x=0.957$$

Answer (score 0):

I put your problem in Mathematica version 10 and its root is $0.956509$
Here is the graphic of the function $f$ in the interval $[-2\pi,2\pi]:$
[image]